# get the count of telegram group members

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I try like that

```
GetChatMemberCount chatMemberCount = new GetChatMemberCount().setChatId(message.getChatId()); 
Integer count = chatMemberCount.deserializeResponse("false");
```

But there were excepetion

> 'Cannot construct instance of
>   org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.ApiResponse
>   (although at least one Creator exists): no boolean/Boolean-argument
>   constructor/factory method to deserialize from boolean value (false)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way, I get the count of the group members.

```
GetChatMemberCount chatMemberCount = new GetChatMemberCount().setChatId(message.getChatId());
try { Integer count = execute(chatMemberCount); } catch (TelegramApiException e) { logger.error(e.getMessage()); }
```